# Converting character dates

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to convert character dates as below in R:

```
Before          After
"31/03/2018"    "201804"
"30/06/2018"    "201807"
"30/09/2018"    "201810"
"31/12/2018"    "201901"
```

The month is advanced by a month. This will be helpful to people trying to convert calendar date to the Canadian fiscal date which follow months 1, 4, 7 and 10 instead of months 3, 6, 9 and 12 elsewhere(generally).

Comment: Did you try anything? Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: `"31/09/2018"` & `"31/06/2018"`  are invalid date.

Comment: Please share what did you try till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't tried anything yet, Here you go:

```
format(as.Date("31/03/2018","%d/%m/%Y")+1,"%Y%m")
format(as.Date(Before,"%d/%m/%Y")+1,"%Y%m")
```

Comment: Have you realized a fact that `"31/09/2018"` is an invalid date?

Answer (score 0):

With lubridate, things are as easy as adding a day :

```
library(lubridate)
before <- c("31/03/2018","30/06/2018","30/09/2018","31/12/2018")
after <- dmy(before)+days(1)
format(after, "%Y%m")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `%m+%` operator is very handy in such case. `%m+% months(1)` will add `1` month in date or `%m+% months(2)` will add 2 months to date. Even one can use `%m+% years(1)` to add `1` year to a date variable.

```
library(lubridate)

v <- c("31/03/2018", "30/06/2018", "30/09/2018", "31/12/2018")


format((dmy(v) %m+% months(1)), "%Y%m")
#[1] "201804" "201807" "201810" "201901"
```